# How to exclude rules in modsecurity corerule set for url encoding

Tags: linux, security, firewall, bash, apache2

The question is simple due to some specific need i want my apache mod_security with latest core rule set v3.3.0 to allow `../` in url encoded form i.e it should not block `..%2f` in the request, and it should block `../` i just want it to allow `..%2f`

https://github.com/coreruleset/coreruleset/blob/v3.4/dev/rules/REQUEST-930-APPLICATION-ATTACK-LFI.conf

I've tried excluding the decoded payload rule id from lfi conf file in core rule set but it doesn't seem to work, can you please guide me how can i accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not required to change ModSecurity's own configuration in order to disable single rules in Apache. This enables you to disable rules on the specific context where they cause problems, e.g. per VirtualHost or per directory, using [`SecRuleRemoveById`](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-%28v2.x%29#SecRuleRemoveById):

```
<ifmodule mod_security3.c>
    SecRuleRemoveById 930100 
</ifmodule>
```

It is better to limit the exception as narrow as possible so that the rule can still protect other parts of your application and other virtual hosts on the same server.

Comment: so i need to add this code to my apache2.conf file ?

Comment: Not only anywhere in `apache2.conf`, but inside the [Configuration Section](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html) where it is needed.

Comment: it actually doesn't works, i added the `SecRuleRemoveById` to apache conf at right location, it is still blocking ..%2f but the error logs are different this time i see other rule id that is blocking request this time. when i tried adding that rule id to apache2.conf it stopped blocking anything, even rce commands were working